# IPython --Notebook goes on circular reference importing django.db.models

Tags: django, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I've been dev in Django for a year, and often I make use of ipython notebook. I have some projects with different config (and environment) that it works well. But with this one, something goes wrong:

Relevant versions:

```
ActivePython 2.7.6.9 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.7.6 (default, Feb 27 2014, 14:06:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin

django-extensions==1.5.2
ipython==2.3.0
pyzmq==14.5.0
tornado==4.0.2
```

using ipython notebook and trying to import models:

```
python manage.py shell_plus --notebook
```

this happens:

[image]

It seems that it is a kind of circular reference with django>db>models.py. This particular problem does not happen while using ipython w/o --notebook

```
python manage.py shell_plus
```

What am I doing wrong?

This problem is driving me crazy :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My circular reference ended up being in settings and not in models.